# the battery condition is ‘Normal’, but the macbook air 2017 can not be used without power supply

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery

I have watched dramas several times that caused my computer to be extremely hot, and then the battery was unable to function properly. However, the battery condition was normal and the number of cycles was only 168.
How should I check if this is a problem with the circuit or the battery?

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store. 5 years is a pretty standard life for a laptop battery: 168 cycles seems very low: perhaps it's been mostly left plugged in all that time.